# Copy values within column, based on other column value

Tags: r, dataframe

Im trying to fill all NA's with another value that occurs in the same column for rows that are in the same month, is there an easy way of doing this? i've found all sorts of functions that do almost, but not quite this.

data.frame looks like this

```
id  month   price1  price2
1    1         NA     2
2    1         4      NA
3    1         NA     NA
1    2         6      NA
2    2         NA     NA
3    2         NA     4
```

output should look like this:

```
id  month   price1  price2
1    1         4     2
2    1         4     2
3    1         4     2
1    2         6     4
2    2         6     4
3    2         6     4
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is to use the `match` function.

```
d <- data.frame(id = rep(1:3, 2),
                month = rep(1:2, each=3),
                price1 = c(NA, 4, NA, 6, NA, NA),
                price2 = c(2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4))

d[is.na(d$price1), "price1"] <-
    d[!is.na(d$price1), ][match(d[is.na(d$price1), "month"],
                                d[!is.na(d$price1), "month"]), "price1"]

d[is.na(d$price2), "price2"] <-
    d[!is.na(d$price2), ][match(d[is.na(d$price2), "month"],
                                d[!is.na(d$price2), "month"]), "price2"]

> d
  id month price1 price2
1  1     1      4      2
2  2     1      4      2
3  3     1      4      2
4  1     2      6      4
5  2     2      6      4
6  3     2      6      4
```

Note that if there is more than one non-missing value to choose from, this method will use the first non-missing value.

As suggested by Laterow, you can loop over the variables:

```
for (j in 3:ncol(d)) {
  varname <- names(d)[j]
  d[is.na(d[, varname]), varname] <-
    d[!is.na(d[, varname]), ][match(d[is.na(d[, varname]), "month"],
                                    d[!is.na(d[, varname]), "month"]),
                              varname]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, would you have a suggestion to iterate this method? i forgot to mention, i have about 400 columns. can i just start the command with "for i in ...." and then replace price1/price2 with i? also, the multiple values don't matter, its always the same price per product per month:)

Comment: @larryfisherman Just replace `d[is.na(d$price1), "price1"]` with `m <- names(d)[i]; d[is.na(d[,m]), m]`, and loop with something like `for (i in 3:ncol(d))`.

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution. It assumes that each "month" has a single value alongside the NA's.

Create a dataframe with a single column for each month and new variables with the single value in them.

```
 d1 <- d %>% group_by(month) 
%>% summarise(price1a = mean(price1,na.rm=TRUE),price2a=mean(price2,na.rm=TRUE))
```

Append the new columns to the original dataframe.

```
dplyr::left_join(d,d1,by="month")
id month price1 price2 price1a price2a
1  1     1     NA      2       4       2
2  2     1      4     NA       4       2
3  3     1     NA     NA       4       2
4  1     2      6     NA       6       4
5  2     2     NA     NA       6       4
6  3     2     NA      4       6       4
```

Answer (score 0):

This question might be better off in StackExchange since it is focused on programming in R, but here's an answer:

I imagine there are better ways to do this, but the one that comes to mind immediately.

```
replace_nas <- function(df,var,id_var,func = function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
    return( merge(df[,-which(names(df)==var)],aggregate(as.formula(paste0(var,"~",id_var)),df,func))[,var])
replace_all_nas <- function(df,id_vars,select_var,agg_vars,func = function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
    return(cbind(df[,id_vars],sapply(agg_vars,function(x) replace_nas(df,x,select_var,func))))
```

Usage: call replace_all_nas with df as the data.frame you want to perform this action on, id_vars is a vector of the names of the columns you want fixed, select_var is the variable you want to organize by, agg_vars are the variables you want to replace the NAs of, func is the function you want to use to collect non-na values to replace the NAs. I set this to select the not NA values, assuming there is only one, but you would need something else to deal with this if you there multiple non-NA values in a column.

Running on your example:

```
replace_all_nas(blah,id_vars = c("id","month"),select_var = c("month"),agg_vars = c("price1","price2"),func = function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
#    id month price1 price2
#  1  1     1      4      2
#  2  2     1      4      2
#  3  3     1      4      2
#  4  1     2      6      4
#  5  2     2      6      4
#  6  3     2      6      4
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be using `ave`. Functions can be applied on groups of same factor levels with `ave`.

```
ave(df$price1, df$month, FUN=function(x)unique(x[!is.na(x)]))

#[1] 4 4 4 6 6 6

ave(df$price2, df$month, FUN=function(x)unique(x[!is.na(x)]))
#[1] 2 2 2 4 4 4
```